# C# - Create .txt file as UTF-8 instead ANSI from plaintext

Tags: c#, utf-8

I input the UTF-8 charachers example `正體字/繁體字` in `plaintext`. i click the button to save the text as `.txt` file but when i click the button to load the `.txt` file to the program again, the question marks `??????` appear in `plaintext`

load `.txt` file

```
richTextBox1.SaveFile("notes.txt", RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
```

save the plaintext as `.txt` file

```
if (File.Exists("notes.txt"))
{
       richTextBox1.LoadFile("notes.txt", RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
}
```

Comment: Tried Type.UnicodePlainText?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UnicodePlainText` instead of `PlainText`:

```
richTextBox1.SaveFile("notes.txt", RichTextBoxStreamType.UnicodePlainText);
```

And do the same when using `LoadFile`.

Comment: oh thanks. i did not know that i could use `UnicodePlainText`